# react-editor-js error: "Cannot call a class as a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, create-react-app, editorjs

I'm trying to set up an editor with `react-editor-js`.

I installed `react-editor-js`, `@editorjs/editorjs`, and almost every single official editor.js plugin.

In my code, I did the following (snipped heavily truncated for brevity):

```
function MyComponent({ text }) {
    return (
        text && (
            <EditorJS data={JSON.parse(text)} tools={EditorJSTools} />
        )
    )
}
```

`EditorJSTools` is just an object containing all the tools. I can't seem to reproduce this problem in any JSFiddle or CodeSandbox, so I assume it's a problem with my environment:

I set up my app with `yarn create react-app --template=electron-builder` and later ejected from CRA because I needed to change the webpack `target` to `electronRenderer` in order to use `electron-store`.

Can anyone spot the problem here? I've been bashing my head against the keyboard for 2 hours now and I can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. This was just a stupid mistake on my end:

Instead of importing `EditorJS` from `react-editor-js`, VSCode Autoimport imported from `@editorjs/editorjs`...‍♂️‍♂️